# How to skip set of files when creating pure WIX patch

Tags: patch, wix3.8

I am working on a patch using pure WIX. How can I exclude one or more files explicitly from the patch. Suppose my baseline image consist of binaryA, Binary B and Binary C. I dont want to included Binary C in my patch creation. Is this feasible when using pure WIX?

I looked at the UpgradeFile element but this is to use with PCP and not with Pure Wix.

Thanks